# Extract diagonal elements (like spdiags in matlab)

Tags: c++, c, matlab, sparse-matrix

I want to implement ,as possible , [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) function in C.

(I prefer C to C++ and I don't want to use C++ algorithms for now)

Having as input matrix:

```
inMx =
     1     0     0
     4     5     6
     0     7     9
```

you should obtain (running that using spdiags in Matlab)  :

```
ouMx =
     4     1     0
     7     5     0
     0     9     6
```

(one thing I can't understand though , is even though at the documentation it says that zeros are inserted at the top if you are below the main diagonal , here you we can see that happens the opposite , but in the example in the link it's ok )

With my code below , I am taking as output:

```
ouMx =
     4     7     0
     7     5     9
     0     9     6
```

so I think I am close!

I zeroed out the output matrix instead of having to insert zeros at the bottom or top of columns.
But I can't completeley handled the above/below the main diagonal.

I used `if ( j > i ) swap rows` , but it doesn't work , so I just use swap rows.

( I am assuming square matrix for this example ,but it should work for any matrix )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void Diag( int Rows , int Cols , float * inMx , float * ouMx );
void swapRows( int Rows , int Cols , float * Mx );

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){

    int Rows = 3 , Cols = 3;  
    float *inMx = (float *) malloc ( Rows * Cols * sizeof (float) );
    float *ouMx = (float *) malloc ( Rows * Cols * sizeof (float) );


    // assume row major order
    inMx[0] = 1.0;
    inMx[1] = 0.0;
    inMx[2] = 0.0;
    inMx[3] = 4.0;
    inMx[4] = 5.0;
    inMx[5] = 6.0;
    inMx[6] = 0.0;
    inMx[7] = 7.0;
    inMx[8] = 9.0;


    // print  input matrix ( row major )
    printf("\n      Input matrix     \n\n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < Rows; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < Cols; j++ ) {
            printf("%f\t",inMx[ i * Cols + j ]);
            if( j == Cols-1 )
                printf("\n");
            }
    printf("\n");

    // extract diagonals
    Diag( Rows , Cols , inMx , ouMx );

    // print Diagonal matrix 
    printf("\n      Diagonal matrix     \n\n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < Rows; i++ )
        for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++ ) {
            printf("%f\t",ouMx[ i * Cols + j ]);
            if( j == Cols-1 )
                printf("\n");
            }

    printf("\n");


    free( inMx );
    free( ouMx );


  return 0;
}


void Diag( int Rows , int Cols , float * inMx , float * ouMx )
{

    //zero out ouMx
    memset( ouMx , 0 , Rows * Cols * sizeof(float) );

    // scan from the last line to the first -1  for each column
    for ( int j = 0; j < Cols; j++ )
    {
        for ( int i = ( Rows - 1 ); i > 0 ; i-- ) 
        {
            // neglect the zero elements
            if ( inMx[ i * Cols + j ] != 0 )
            {
                ouMx[ i * Cols + j ] = inMx[ i * Cols + j ];

                //if the element in the next colulmn is !=0
                if ( inMx[ ( i + 1 ) * Cols + ( j + 1 ) ] != 0 )
                {
                    ouMx[ ( i + 1 ) * Cols + j ] = inMx[ ( i + 1 ) * Cols + ( j + 1 ) ];

                }

            }
            //if we are above the main diagonal
            //swap elements of a row (in each column) in order to have the zeros at bottom/top
            // if ( i > j ) doesn't work
            swapRows( Rows , Cols , ouMx );
        }


    }


}


void swapRows( int Rows , int Cols , float * Mx )
{

    float temp;

    for ( int j = 0; j < Cols; j++ )
    { 
        for ( int i = ( Rows - 1 ); i > 0 ; i-- ) 
        {

            temp = Mx[ ( i - 1 ) * Cols + j ];
            Mx[ ( i - 1 ) * Cols + j ] = Mx[ i * Cols + j ];
            Mx[ i * Cols + j ] = temp;

        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise or do you actually want a performant algorithm for extracting nonzero diagonals from a matrix?  If the latter, I would suggest you find a library - this approach is not going to be fast and there are a lot of mistakes to correct in this code...  You've also tagged this both `c` and `c++` - are you willing to use a C++ solution?

Comment: @J...: I am doing this for me.But it's good to have a good perfomance also.I prefer using C and not C++ algoritmhs etc.Thanks

Comment: Problem 1 is that you have already `malloc`d your output array before you even know what size it is going to be.  You've made it the same size as your input array when it could have as many as `i + j - 1` diagonals (and as few as zero, which is a case you have to handle!).  You are only testing for zero on single elements rather than on complete diagonals - the entire approach is not correct.  You have to extract a complete diagonal, test its entire contents for zero, and then decide whether or not to add it to the output.

Comment: Your algorithm should iterate up the leftmost column, fetching the sub-main diagonals (and main diagonal last), then across the top row fetching all the diagonals above the main diagonal.  Only once you are done will you have a full count of the size of your output matrix - then you can set about allocating space for (and building) your output array.

Comment: @J...:Ok , I will check with these , thanks! I missed the 'p' size of output matrix , thanks!